# How to get the rendered content from the `link` function of a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Html code:

```
<div class="test">{{name}}</div>
```

Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('test', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var content = elm.html();
      alert(content);
    }
  }
});
```

It will alert a string `{{name}}`. How to alert the rendered string `World`?

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mov0AlkdE9B8yKiBjpnp?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [$interpolate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate) service to do this

```
app.directive('test', function($interpolate){
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var content = elm.html();
      alert($interpolate(content)(scope))
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1hnUtAhcr23lYQpgIzw?p=preview)

Comment: Possible to get the content before the template is rendered? i.e. if your directive contains a string before js has executed, to grab that string and use it in the directive.