# How to get the compiled content of an Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to get rendered content inside an Angular directive. Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [1,2,3,4]
});
app.directive('pane', function($interpolate, $compile){
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope:true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var text = element.html();
            var content = $interpolate(text)(scope);
            alert(content);               
       }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='appCtrl'>
<pane>
    <span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}, </span>
</pane>
</div>
```

So, but when I run it, I only get "" in alert box

ps: I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673134/how-to-get-the-rendered-content-from-the-link-function-of-a-directive) but it doesn't work to

Comment: I used your code almost as-is and it renders fine. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83Lxd5vr/)

Comment: I am talking about the content in alert box, because I wanted to modify the content of directive based on original content :) thanks for fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to get directive content from the compile function.

For example:

```
app.directive('pane', function($interpolate, $compile){
    return {
       restrict: 'E',

       compile: function(tElement, attrs){

            var content = tElement.children();
            console.log(tElement);
            $(tElement).empty();
            for(i=1;i<10;i++){
                console.log(1);
                tElement.append(content.clone());
            }   
            return {
                post: function(scope, element, attrs){
                    console.log(scope.items);
                }
            }
       },

    }
});
```